# Creating a new application window in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

When I try to create a new application window in eclipse it doesn't work. I don't know if its because I'm using Mac or not since its working for PC users. When I try to create an application window it says:

> The selected wizard could not be started.
>   Plug-in org.eclipse.wb.swing was unable to load class org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.wizards.application.NewSwingApplicationWizard.
>   An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.wb.swing (958).

If someone could help me with this I would be very greatful:))

Comment: what is an "application window (in eclipse)" ?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for a more detailed error message. Note that this directory is hidden on macOS so you won't be able to see it in Finder,